# UIImagePickerController.InfoKey does not contain UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset entry when accessing simulators or iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to get all metadata from image files in iPhone and iPad libraries from the photo library. In order to do this I am adding code into the code below which runs after selecting an image from the photo library:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

  }
```

when the code runs on an iPhone 8 running iOS 15.6 the info parameter contains 5 entries, one of which has the key "UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset". When the code runs on an iPad, the iPhone 8 simulator or the iPad iOS 15.5 simulator  there are only 4 entries and the key "UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset" is not present. There is no Settings value for the app on the iPad and on the iPad  8 simulator. In the iPad simulator the only Settings options for the app are Add Photo and None. Is there a way of ensuring that All Photos access can be provided on the iPad or the simulators?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the app requires permission to access photos and until there is a Settings entry this cannot be assigned from Settings. The permission can be set programmatically as per https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/delivering_an_enhanced_privacy_experience_in_your_photos_app. Adding this in the viewWillAppear function of the main form ensures that users should only need to set it once. However, iOS 14 or newer is required.